# Retain query params while changing url path

Tags: javascript

I am currently on the following endpoint.

```
http://www.mydomaintest.com/first_path?param1=1&param2=2
```

I am looking to change this to following where the path is now `/new_path`:

```
http://www.mydomaintest.com/new_path?param1=1&param2=2
```

Currently performing the following command which does change the path, but it removes the query params.

```
window.location.href = '/new_path';
```

How can I change the path but still retain the query params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing `href` just change the `pathname`, like this:

```js
window.location.pathname = '/new_path';
```

It will update the `URL` and will retain the `query params`.